# Bulkification of SingleEmailMessage

Tags: apex, email, governorlimits, bestpractice, bulkification

I'm trying to bulkify my code, and send all emails out as part of a list however I'm receiving the following error;

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [List].setTargetObjectId(Id)

What do I need to amend so it works?

```
global class OpOwnerOldService_Scheduled Implements Schedulable
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
        sendEmailtoOppOwner();
    }

    public void sendEmailtoOppOwner()
    {
        List<Opportunity> listOpportunity = new List<Opportunity>();
        listOpportunity = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Name, Owner.FirstName, (SELECT Id, Product2.Name FROM OpportunityLineItems WHERE Product2.Opportunity_Owner_Notification__c = FALSE
                        AND Product2.Isactive = FALSE
                        AND (Product2.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Unavailable_R_D_Service' OR Product2.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Unavailable_R_D_Project' ) LIMIT 1)
                       FROM Opportunity WHERE Id In
                       (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2.Opportunity_Owner_Notification__c = FALSE
                        AND Product2.Isactive = FALSE
                        AND (Product2.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Unavailable_R_D_Service' OR Product2.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Unavailable_R_D_Project' ))];

        List<Opportunity>emailOpOwner = new list<Opportunity>();
        for(Opportunity opp : listOpportunity)
        {
          List <Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mail = new list <Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

                mail.setTargetObjectId(opp.OwnerId);
                mail.setReplyTo('glenn.daly@live.com');
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
            for(opportunitylineitem oppLineItem :opp.opportunitylineitems)                
                mail.setSubject('Historic Service attached to current opportunity : ' + oppLineItem.Product2.Name);
                String body = 'Hi '+ opp.Owner.FirstName + ', ';     
                body += '<br><br>Salesforce recognises you as the owner of the following opportunity:'+ opp.Name;
            for(opportunitylineitem oppLineItem :opp.opportunitylineitems)
                body += '<br><br>Attached to this opportunity is a former R&D service or project that is no longer available:' + oppLineItem.Product2.Name;
                body += '<br><br> Please use the link below to view the opportunity record:';
                body += '<br><br>test.salesforce.com/'+ opp.id;     
                mail.setHtmlBody(body);
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                emailOpOwner.add(mail);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
        }
                    update listOpportunity;

Map<Id, Product2> products = new Map<Id, Product2>();
for(Opportunity opp: listOpportunity) {
    for(OpportunityLineItem oppLineItem: opp.opportunitylineitems) {
        products.put(oppLineItem.Product2Id, new Product2(Id=oppLineItem.Product2Id, Opportunity_Owner_Notification__c=true));
        }
    }
                    update products.values();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should instead be:

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
for Opportunity record : records)
{
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage()
    // set properties on singular email
    emails.add(email);
}
Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
```